# How to search for a particular key in a key value pair and return the corresponding value of it using sql function

Tags: sql, sql-function

Suppose the function is taking two inputs 4 and '3:66,8:54,4:23' , the function should search for 4 in the key value pair '3:66,8:54,4:23' , if key 4 is found then it should return corresponding value of it i,e:23 else it should return empty. How to write the function for it in sql.

Comment: Any solution for it?

Comment: You can start by tagging your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us the database product you are using.

In [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/) you can do that using `string_to_array()` combined with `split_part()`:

```
select split_part(x.kv, ':', 2)
from unnest(string_to_array('3:66,8:54,4:23', ',')) as x(kv)
where split_part(x.kv, ':', 1) = '4';
```

You can put that into a SQL function:

```
create function get_key_value(p_input text, p_key text)
  returns text
as
$$
    select split_part(x.kv, ':', 2)
    from unnest(string_to_array(p_input, ',')) as x(kv)
    where split_part(x.kv, ':', 1) = p_key;
$$
language sql;
```

Then use:

```
select get_key_value(''3:66,8:54,4:23'', '4');
```